# Can I set a "is a Discriminated Union" type constraint on a generic argument in F# type declaration?

Tags: types, f#, abstraction, discriminated-union, generic-type-parameters

I am creating a type system for some generic types of common input:

```
// type Validator<'t> when 't :> ??? = Validator of 't
// with member x.validate value condition =
//         if condition then
//             (true, Some ('t value))
//         else
//             (false, None)

module Validatable =
    let validate t value condition =        
        if condition then
            (true, Some (t value))
        else
            (false, None)

type Email = Email of string
with member x.validate(s) = Validatable.validate Email s (Regex.IsMatch(s, ""))

type Name = Name of string
with member x.validate(s) = Validatable.validate Name s (Regex.IsMatch(s, ""))

type PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber of string
with member x.validate(s) = Validatable.validate PhoneNumber s (Regex.IsMatch(s, ""))
```

You'll see that within the comment, I have another type commented out. I am hoping to use the type defined within the comment to replace the functionality of the `validate t value condition` function within the `Validatable` module.

What do I need to replace the ??? with to allow me to say that the generic parameter `'t` is the case identifier of a Discriminated Union?

Comment: No, you cannot. This looks like an XY problem. Would you mind sharing more of the context, exactly why you'd like to do this? Also, why are you returning a bool paired with an option rather than just the option alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union case isn't a type, it's a function that produces a value of type. So you can write your `Validator` type like this instead:

```ml
type Validator<'inp, 'out> = Validator of ('inp -> 'out)
with member x.validate value condition =
        let (Validator f) = x
        if condition then
            (true, Some (f value))
        else
            (false, None)
```

And use it like this:

```ml
type Email = Email of string
with member x.validate(s) = (Validator Email).validate s (Regex.IsMatch(s, ""))

type Name = Name of string
with member x.validate(s) = (Validator Name).validate s (Regex.IsMatch(s, ""))

type PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber of string
with member x.validate(s) = (Validator PhoneNumber).validate s (Regex.IsMatch(s, ""))
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Also, if you're willing to offer your opinion, is using this generic type constraint better than the module/function approach?

Comment: I'd have to know more about what you're trying to do, but in general writing a single `validate` function is simpler than creating an entire `Validator` type. So I'd lean towards the simpler module/function approach unless there's a reason you need a type.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to tell what are you actually trying to do. But if you want to write some function that works on multiple types of values, you generally can use interfaces and do not need generic type constraints.

For example, if you wanted to have a generic way of validating certain kinds of values using regular expressions, you could define an `IValidable` interface:

```
type IValidable = 
  abstract Value : string
  abstract ValidationRegex : string
```

Then implement the interface in all the types you want to validate:

```
type Email = 
  | Email of string
  interface IValidable with
    member x.Value = let (Email v) = x in v
    member x.ValidationRegex = "[a-z]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+"
  
type PhoneNumber = 
  | PhoneNumber of string
  interface IValidable with
    member x.Value = let (PhoneNumber v) = x in v
    member x.ValidationRegex = "[0-9]+"
```

And now you can write a simple `validate` function and use it with all your values:

```
let validate (v:IValidable) =
  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(v.Value, v.ValidationRegex)
  
validate (Email "no")
validate (Email "no@no.no")
validate (PhoneNumber "no")
validate (PhoneNumber "123")
```